# selected dropdown height overflow

Tags: flutter

so i have this dropdown and the `DropdownMenuItem` i have `ListTile`, below is the option result

[image]

after i select it the result become like this

[image]

Here is my script

```
Visibility(
                visible: _signalEmiten != null,
                child: Container(
                  height: 150.w,
                  child: FutureBuilder<List<Mt5Model>>(
                    future: getData(),
                    builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
                      if (snapshot.hasError) {
                        return Text("ERROR PLEASE RE OPEN SCREEN");
                      }
                      return snapshot.hasData
                          ? Container(
                              child: DropdownButtonFormField(
                                itemHeight: 150.w,
                                decoration: InputDecoration(
                                  labelText: 'Choose Account',
                                ),
                                items: snapshot.data
                                    .map<DropdownMenuItem>((Mt5Model item) {
                                  return DropdownMenuItem(
                                    value: item.mt5Id,
                                    child: Container(
                                      padding:
                                          EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 5.w),
                                      width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width *
                                          .80,
                                      child: ListTile(
                                        dense: true,
                                        //leading: Text(item.mt5Id.toString()),
                                        title: Text("123456"),
                                        subtitle: Column(
                                          mainAxisAlignment:
                                              MainAxisAlignment.start,
                                          crossAxisAlignment:
                                              CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                                          children: [
                                            Text("Account Type : " + "Type 1"),
                                            Text("Equity : \$ " + "XXXX"),
                                          ],
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                  );
                                }).toList(),
                                onChanged: (value) {
                                  setState(() {
                                    dropDownValue = value;
                                    populateAccount();
                                  });
                                },
                              ),
                            )
                          : Container(
                              child: Center(
                                child: Text('Loading...'),
                              ),
                            );
                    },
                  ),
                ),
              ),
```

i already trying to increate the height of my `container` and `DropdownButtonFormField` height, but still no help. So, how can i fix it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here I tried to solve the issue, you need to wrap the ListTile subtitle with SingleChildScrollView and enable isThreeLine.you can check with the example below.

```
void main() => runApp( const MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const MaterialApp(
      home: DropDownExample(),
    );
  }
}

class DropDownExample extends StatefulWidget {
  const DropDownExample({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _DropDownExampleState createState() => _DropDownExampleState();
}

class _DropDownExampleState extends State<DropDownExample> {
  String dropDownValue = "rohit";

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
          child: DropdownButtonFormField(
        itemHeight: 100,
        decoration: const InputDecoration(
            labelText: 'Choose Account',
            contentPadding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 30)),//Fit the content on dropdown selected value
        menuMaxHeight: 300,
        value: dropDownValue,
        isExpanded: true,
        isDense: true,
        iconSize: 30,
        items: ["rohit", "manish"].map<DropdownMenuItem>((item) {
          return DropdownMenuItem(
            value: item,
            child: Container(
              width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * .80,
              child: ListTile(
                dense: false,
                //leading: Text(item.mt5Id.toString()),
                isThreeLine: true, //getting extra height for ListTile
                title: Text("123456"),
                subtitle: Container(
                  color: Colors.yellow,
                  child: SingleChildScrollView( //to solve over flow issues
                    child: Column(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                      children: [
                        Text("Equity : \$ " + item),
                        Text("Account Type : " + "Type 1"),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          );
        }).toList(),
        onChanged: _te,
      )),
    );
  }

  void _te(value) {
    setState(() {
      dropDownValue = value.toString();
      // populateAccount();
    });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to remove first container

```
height: 150.w,
```